# inside package

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Similar to the [Embed ()] tag I know from flex ¿ what's for the following code:

```
[Event(name="init",type="flash.events.Event")]
[Event(name="ioError",type="flash.events.IOErrorEvent")]
[Event(name="securityError",type="flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent")]
```

I've found this in several libraries I used, the one show here is from Flartoolkit, the code is defined inside the package, after the imports.

By the way, is this code executed when I compile in flash IDE?

Thanks,
.am

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actionscript's metadata tags. These specific ones declare that the class below them throws these kind of events of these types.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/metadata_3.html#159710

This metadata gets bound to the class at runtime and is available for access

Comment: Thanks artemb, I suppose that flash compiler won't read those right?

Comment: I guess it will. It will also remove some of them is you specify a certain parameter

Answer (score 2):

[`Event`] metadata is for the Flex framework and are not used by the Flash IDE, but you can use of the [[`Embed`]](http://flashauthoring.blogspot.com/2008/09/flash-cs4-and-flex-metadata.html) metadata under Flash CS4

Comment: thanks for the info, here's the source:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/embed_metadata.html

:)